# iOS NSURLConnection doesn't call connectionDidFinishLoading

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsurlconnection

I have a `UIViewController` with `UITableView`.

In my `viewDidLoad` method I call `NSURLConnection`:`[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self]`.

After this, I assume, `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods such as `didReceiveResponse` should be called. My idea is to get data and to fill table with it.

But actually, after `NSURLConnection` call, `UITableViewDataSource` methods are called before `didReceiveResponse` method. Because of this, I can't initialise table view with new data.

Why? How to fix it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Reload tableview in `connectionDidFinishLoading`. If it is not calling the issue will be in your code, without any code can't say anything on that.

Comment: When do you call `reloadData` on your `UITableView`?

Comment: Your title says that connectionDidFinishLoading isn't called. Do you know that for a fact, or are you basing that on your table view being empty?

Comment: It is called. But it is called after table view data source methods. Is it possible to make it be called before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you had an array with the elements you have to show on your UITableView

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    // Update data from the response to your elements array
    ...

    // Reload Data
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by using the UITableView reloadData method after receiving new information or by inserting new rows at specific indexes so the whole UITableView does not update.